# Supporting multiple graphics apis

Tags: c++, architecture, software-engineering, graphics-programming

I would like to provide support for switching between both OpenGL and Vulkan in my game (and potentially DX12 later).  Currently I only know OpenGL so I am working on that.

I have read a lot of posts about supporting multiple apis.  Thus far I have been creating a non-specific interface with virtual functions for which I then create a .h/.cpp for the the OpenGL specific implementation.  For example, I have a `GraphicsDevice.h` and a `GLGraphicsDevice.h` and `GLGraphicsDevice.cpp`.  I then have this in my initialisation code:

```
GLGraphicsDevice gl_graphics_device = GLGraphicsDevice(&gl_window);
GraphicsDevice* graphics_device = &gl_graphics_device;
```

Using the above approach I would have to determine somehow whether `graphics_device` would be `GLGraphicsDevice` or `VKGraphicsDevice` which I would most likely do using a configuration file.

I recently came across a different approach of handling multiple apis suggesting the use of macros:

1. Have a base class with the common data e.g., `IndexBufferBase`.
2. Each API class (e.g. `GLIndexBuffer`) inherits from the base class and handles API-specific functionality, such as creating the index buffer and drawing with it.
3. `IndexBuffer` inherits from one of the API classes depending on which macro is set.

I'm not sure how I would set the macros for the above approach.

I've read that macros should be avoided but I've also read that virtual function calls are costly, so which is the better approach?  Or perhaps there is another option?

**Edit**: Based on helpful feedback in the comments I have narrowed my goal to providing compile-time support for multiple apis.

Comment: Is it important to you to be able to switch between rendering backends at runtime or would it be sufficient to have a compiler flag which allows you to choose for which graphic API you are compiling for?

Comment: @Philipp Thanks for your reply.  I'd like to analyse both options as I still don't properly understand the tradeoffs.  Common opinion seems to be that switching at runtime is overkill for a solo dev?  However, if I want to release the game with OpenGL support but later give users the choice between OpenGL and Vulkan via say a config file then I think I will need runtime support.

Comment: IMO, supporting more than one rendering API is *already* overkill for a solo developer. If you ask me, for 99% of 3d solo projects, dealing with 3d rendering APIs *at all* is overkill and it would be far better to just use a game engine. (Did you know Unreal now costs nothing until your first million dollar of revenue?)

Comment: If you want to leave the choice to the user, you could just ship your game with multiple executables for multiple rendering backends.

Comment: @Philipp I'd say those recommendations together could be an upvote-worthy answer to the question.

Comment: @Philipp Thanks.  So if I went with the multiple executable route I would use the second of my two original methods (macros) and have a compiler flag?  When would it be desirable to be able to switch at runtime?

Comment: When you want an options menu entry where the player can switch between different render backends and apply their change without having to leave the game.

Comment: @Philipp OK, I won't need that.  Presumably I could give the users a small standalone game configuration tool to allow them to select their renderer, which would in turn run the correct executable?

Comment: @MasterReDWinD If you ship all binaries to all users, yes... It just depends which one you launch. Bear in mind that multiple binaries may add complications outside your application (eg I have a restrictive firewall that requires explicit approval before each binary can access the internet. In your case, the first few times I switch rendering engine, I'd need to re-approve internet access).

Comment: @Basic Thanks for that.  Is there a more standardised way of handling it?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have the experience in distributing c++ to give you a weighty answer. FWIW my personal opinion is that you should be shipping a single binary to launch. Seems like it would be simpler if (say) you ever want to distribute by Steam and don't want a multi-choice menu on every launch. There's nothing to say that binary can't use a config file to determine which of _n_ implementations of an interface it loads from companion assemblies, or have all three implementations built-in and switched between at runtime.

Comment: @Basic Thanks for your input all the same.  I'll look into your idea regarding "There's nothing to say that binary can't use a config file to determine which of n implementations of an interface it loads from companion assemblies".

Comment: In case you haven't found the right keywords yet... Dynamically linked libraries (.dll) on windows, Shared Objects (.so) on linux. You may also be interested in static libraries (.a).

Comment: @Basic Thanks for that.